# My flutter app is not showing anything in build after some time

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I made build of app. After making a build its was working properly but suddenly it's stopped showing icons assets and widgets.

1. [image: it's picture of app that's work perfect]

After sometime.
[image: image after sometime]
I tried to flutter clean, checked debug and logs section for any errors but didn't not find any error

Comment: Hi Shubham, the community will not be able to help you with your issue unless you show us the actual code that causes that behaviour, so please provide a minimal reproducible example.